# Attempting to upload a pdf from a html form

Tags: php, html

Here I'm trying to upload a PDF file from a html form. But the file is not being uploaded.

**HTML file:**

```
<form action="Upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">                  
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload"  accept="application/pdf" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>
```

**Upload.php file:**

```
move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['fileToUpload'] ['tmp_name'], "uploads/{$_FILES['fileToUpload'] ['name']}");
```

Comment: Is there any error? edit your question with more details.

Comment: check file permission is set to 777 or not

Comment: Do you check the return value of `move_uploaded_file`? It's a success boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Check you have created "upload" folder in your root directory.

Answer (score -1):

edit in your upload.php

```html
move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['fileToUpload'] ['tmp_name'], "uploads/".$_FILES['fileToUpload'] ['name']);
```

also check permission to your upload folder to 777